# Chart with multiple series on each row

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to do an *iReport* chart with this table

```
name|totalcalls|handled|abandoned|rejected

customerservice|300|100|100|100

itsupport|500|300|100|100
```

The idea is that there should be 2 charts in this case, that was easily solved by putting the chart into the details row.

But I cannot figure out how to make *iReport* treat the 3 last columns (handled, abandoned, rejected) as different series.

Ideally I want to do a stacked barchart that looks like this:

```
customerservice|-100-|-100-|-100-

itsupport|---300---|-100-|100
```

I have no clue how to make this work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a stacked bar chart. Open iReport and drag and drop the chart element from the palette to the report designer. In the wizard select *Stacked Bar*, then click *Finish*.

Right click on the chart and select *Chart Data* > *Details*:

- click *Add*, enter Series Expression: `"Handled"`, Category Expression: `$F{name}`, Value Expression: `$F{handled}`, click *Ok*
- *Add*, Series Expression: `"Abandoned"`, Category Expression: `$F{name}`, Value Expression: `$F{abandoned}`, *Ok*
- *Add*, Series Expression: `"Rejected"`, Category Expression: `$F{name}`, Value Expression: `$F{rejected}`, *Ok*

Then click *Close*. Now select the chart object in the report designer and change in the properties panel *Orientation* to *horizontal*.

I put the chart into the summary band holding both rows of data in a single chart. You can apply the same settings for the chart being configured in the detail band for a similar output  if required.

[image: report preview]

I also attach the JRXML for further reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report7" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="42d0d6ab-85f6-496b-8e61-c3d7588cfd8e">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select  'customerservice' as name, 300 as totalcalls, 100 as handled, 100 as abandoned, 100 as rejected
union select 'itsupport', 500, 300, 100, 100]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="totalcalls" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="handled" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="abandoned" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="rejected" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="92">
            <stackedBarChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement uuid="f0bfeda6-003e-40c0-8d75-0c61bc620978" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="92"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Handled"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{handled}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Abandoned"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{abandoned}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Rejected"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{rejected}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </barPlot>
            </stackedBarChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```